# How can I create an instance of a service (injectable) with Angular inside a class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, ngxs

```
import { Store } from '@ngxs/store';
export class Service {

    constructor(private _store: Store) {}
}

export abstract class A {
    constructor( private _service: Service ) {  }
}

export class B extends A {
    constructor( private _service: Service ) {
        super(_service);
    }
}
```

I'd like to avoid B (and other 10 classes like B) to declare and pass that service to A.
I was reading about using ReflectiveInjector, but apparently it works only when all providers got @Injectable() decorator, which is not provided in Store.

Any idea if and how is doable?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an instance of a class if you also insert the dependency:

```
public store: Store = new Store()    
public service: Service = new Service(this.store);
```